# Windows 8.1 App certification fails for invalid OSVersion and image size

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to update my WinJS app to the new Windows Dev Center. 
I checked the app before uploading with the App Cert Kit 3.4 on Windows 8.1 and everything was fine.

On the submission process the app failed at certification:

- **OSMinVersion/OSMaxVersion** attribute is invalid
- Splashscreen **image size** is wrong (should be 480x800)

My appxmanifest defines the OS version:

```
<Prerequisites>
   <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
   <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
</Prerequisites>
```

I thought 6.3.1 was right for Windows 8.1.

The strange thing about the image size is that Visual Studio 2013 on Win8.1 tells me that the size of the asset splashscreen should be 620x30. It won't even let me build a appx package with a size of 480x800. Installed Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine - same with the image size.

I also installed the latest WACK tool from the Win10 SDK and I got the same errors on this certification process as the ones on the Store submission.

Which OS version should I define? How can I apply a image size that is marked as invalid on the corresponding IDE? (do I need to manipulate the appxbundle afterwards?)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution to the problem:
My app package was defined as the following:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"
         xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest"
         xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest"
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">

....

</Package>
```

I removed the xmlns:mp schema (won't be used anyway on this appxmanifest) and the WACK tool proceeds without any error :)